# How can I solve this nested symbolic function?

Tags: function, matlab, nested

Im doing a metallurgical problem in Matlab,to do so I need to make the following code but returns an error when i call the following nested function, by the way I am doing so because I want to export it as an excel add-in .

```
valor=molienda(10,6,6,6.1,1.02,0.45,0.7,10)

function a=molienda(F_min,Diametro,Largo,Wi,F80,Vp,fVc,t)
p80=mP80(t);
%Potencia para moler el mineral
W_mineral=Wi*((10/(p80^0.5))-(10/(F80))^(0.5));
P_mineral=W_mineral*F_min*1.341;
%Potencia para mover el medio moledor
Kwb = 4.879*(D^0.3)*(3.2-3*Vp)*fVc*(1-0.1/((2^9)-10*fVc))
W_bolas=80*(Diametro^2)*Largo;
P_bolas=Kwb*W_bolas;
P_total=P_bolas+P_mineral;
a(1)=P_total;
a(2)=P80;
function P_80=mP80(tiempo)
syms Q(x) z
Q(x) = (16.4831*x^(-0.7510)+1.665)*exp(-0.9451*tiempo^0.296);
fun= 80-(100-Q(z))==0;
P_80 = double(solve(fun,z));
end
end
```

I can´t find the solution ,please if you know how to i would very pleased . Thanks in advance for your help.

Tried to change variables , but not work.

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message. It’s kinda hard to figure out what is wrong without seeing the error message.

Answer (score 2):

[As per documentation, under limitation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html?searchHighlight=syms&s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_syms#mw_7198cd93-7d6a-4e57-8b1e-ce4836f8459b), `syms z` cannot be used in functions, instead `z=sym('z')`

So the `mP80` function body may be rewritten as (also fixing the convoluted syntax) as:

```
function P_80=mP80(tiempo)
x=sym('x') ;
Q = (16.4831*x^(-0.7510)+1.665)*exp(-0.9451*tiempo^0.296);
fun= 80-(100-Q)==0;
P_80 = double(solve(fun,x));
end
```

Aside from this, the `D` variable on line `Kwb = 4.879*(D^0.3)*(3.2-3*Vp)*fVc*(1-0.1/((2^9)-10*fVc))` is not defined an will throw an error. I guess you wanted to use the variable `Diametro` instead.

Also there is another typo on line `a(2)=P80;`, it is supposed to be lower case p, so `a(2)=p80;`

After all the corrections this code runs smoothly, up to you to evaluate if the results are satisfactory:

```
valor=molienda(10,6,6,6.1,1.02,0.45,0.7,10)

function a=molienda(F_min,Diametro,Largo,Wi,F80,Vp,fVc,t)
p80=mP80(t);
%Potencia para moler el mineral
W_mineral=Wi*((10/(p80^0.5))-(10/(F80))^(0.5));
P_mineral=W_mineral*F_min*1.341;
%Potencia para mover el medio moledor
Kwb = 4.879*(Diametro^0.3)*(3.2-3*Vp)*fVc*(1-0.1/((2^9)-10*fVc))
W_bolas=80*(Diametro^2)*Largo;
P_bolas=Kwb*W_bolas;
P_total=P_bolas+P_mineral;
a(1)=P_total;
a(2)=p80;
function P_80=mP80(tiempo)
x=sym('x') ;
Q = (16.4831*x^(-0.7510)+1.665)*exp(-0.9451*tiempo^0.296);
fun= 80-(100-Q)==0;
P_80 = double(solve(fun,x));
end
end
```